# How should I call the superclass's custom initialiser, when I use a custom one for my subclass?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, initialization, subclassing

I'm learning Objective-C and I don't clearly understand what is the best way to call superclass' custom initializer, while defining one in its subclass.

Here is my class' (superclass) custom initializer:

```
-(id) initWithWidth:(int)w andHeight:(int)h {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        [self setWidth:w andHeight:h];
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype) init {
    return [self initWithWidth:0 andHeight:0];
}
```

Here I call its superclass' (`NSObject`) initializer and assign it to `self`. After checking that `self` is not `nil`, I call a method defined in the class. After that, assuming that my custom initializer is a designated one, I override the standard `init`.

Now, I create a subclass of that class. The subclass also has a custom initializer. Here it is:

```
-(id) initWithSide:(int)side {
    self = [super initWithWidth:side andHeight:side];

    if (self) {
        [self setSide: side];
    }
    return self;
}

-(instancetype) init {
    return [self initWithSide:0];
}
```

The logic is the same (again, it calls a custom method defined inside the class).

The problem is, I'm not quite sure what is the right way of calling its superclass' initializer (I still should call it, right?). In forums I've seen that some people don't call it at all, and that confuses me.

Should I call the designated initializer of the superclass or don't call it at all. If you could explain me how this works and the right choice in this case (or best practices, maybe), I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Your code is completely correct. _"In forums I've seen that some people don't call it at all"_ Either those people are doing it wrong, or there's some non-obvious important difference in their code.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, so I should always call the immediate superclass' designated initializer, right?

Comment: From the designated initializer of the subclass, yes, correct. Apple used to have a great diagram of this, but I can't find it now. There's a funnel shape: all non-designated initializers in a class should end up inside its own D.I. The D.I. itself should call the superclass's D.I.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, I got it. Thank you!